# TF31003 when trying to connect to Visual Studio Team Services from VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

we are working on have a small mini project, we want to use visual studio team services online and check in our code in to that so that we can work on the project as a team

created an account and started in to https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs

After creating account got the URL details to my mail **Your account URL -** https://xyzproject.visualstudio.com/

Next , from my project in Visual studio 2012, View tab --> Team Explorer --> Connect to team foundation server --> Servers --> Add -->

```
Name or URL of Team foundation server | https://xyzproject.visualstudio.com/
Path                                  | TFS
Port No                               | 8080
Protocol                              | HTTP
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error : An error has occurred with the script on the page.
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: PS port should be `443`, protocol: `https` and path `/``, unless your Visual Studio instance grays out. Also make sure you've installed VS2012 update 5.

Comment: You could also try using the "Open in Visual Studio" link on the your Visual Studio Team Services Project page.

Comment: Your post contained the same type in the Url. Ensure you prefix the correct protocol: `https://xyzproject.visualstudio.com/`

Comment: I am using windows 7, installed VS2012 update 5, https protocol and 443 port... i have given the Url as https://xyzproject.visualstudio.com , path is given as tfs by default in the window ... It is showing script error popup, object doesn't support this action.

Comment: Try clearing your IE cookies, your IE cache and remove your credentials for Visualstudio.com in the windows credential manager.

Comment: In the windows credential manager i dont see any credentials.. under windows credentials tab it is showing No windows credentials.... FYI i did not download TFS, i am just trying to connect it online using visual studio team foundation services...

Comment: I understand. Under Web credentials there could be a Microsoft Account / live id credential.

Comment: In the credential manager i find 3 types,  windows credentials : No windows credentials, certificate based credentials : No certificates , Generic credentials : No generic credentials ....

Comment: What's the IE version installed on your machine?

Comment: IE 8 is the version installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the settings you entered is correct as Jesse mentioned. The protocol should be "https" and port should be "443". And then reset your IE to default settings and then try again. If the issue still occurs, then check your IE version and upgrade it to IE 11. Check this link for reference: [Troubleshooting connections from Internet Explorer & Visual Studio to Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fb58cf-35fb-4653-8d00-93f51e7cda31/troubleshooting-connections-from-internet-explorer-visual-studio-to-visual-studio-online?forum=TFService).

Comment: Thank you, after upgrading to IE 11 , it is working fine..... after connecting to team services, under visual studio team services i selected get started, can i know how can i check in my code here ? i dont see any options..

Comment: Double clicking your project under VSTS connection, you will see the Team Explorer UI. If you use TFVC for version control, you can check in your code from "Pending Changes". If you use Git, then you need to commit your code from "Changes" and then push it to VSTS from "Sync".

Comment: In the team explorer the check in button is disabled, it is showing there are no pending changes.... this is first time iam checking in.

Comment: Then it didn't detect any changes to check in. Seems you are using TFVC  for version control, did you create the workspace after connection to the project? And did you make any changes after workspace is created? Here is an instruction for TFVC: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs